# TDE state is changed after DB deployment

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have database projects in Visual Studio 2013 from which I deploying databases to SQL Server. Also I am using Transparent Data Encryption for these databases and it is in state 3 which means TDE is ON.

Issue becoming when I deploy databases. After database deployment TDE state is 1 which means TDE is OFF. I only know that Database Encryption Key exist in database page level and I supposed that something happened there when DB schema is changed.

My question is how I can control that process? How I can save TDE state to be 3 after deployment?

I can run SQL query which will turn on TDE but is there any other way?

Comment: You can use `ALTER DATABASE db_name SET ENCRYPTION OFF / ON`. So before the deployment, you can set encryption OFF and after deployment, you can turn it ON. You can even check the status `encryption_state` of encryption using `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` and accordingly run the above alter database statement.

Comment: I've ran TDE for a few years and through numerous deployments and never had to turn it on or off during a deployment using SQL Server 2008 with code deployed from an earlier version of VS.  I suspect a script in the deployment process or some other method is causing TDE to turn off.  Can you record any ALTER DATABASE commands before your deployment to review?  I one saw a odd database corruption issue on TDE, can you re-encrypt without any issues?

Comment: @Kin Thanks fro your respond, but as I mentioned before I don't want to turn ON or turn OF TDE with SQL statements. I want TDE to be always turned ON.

Comment: @ivan.petrovic TDE is not an instance wide setting, if you deploy a new database or overwrite an existing database you would have to enable it for each new/restored database.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I would hope there would be a setting you could add to the publish file so you can keep it enabled or disabled for different environments.